# C++, memory and arrays. Creating my own hashmap for exercise. Unexpected data left in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, variable-initialization

So i'm trying to create a pretty specific for my needs hashmap for a small project where i'm trying to learn c++. I have the following code:

```
template<class T>
class HashMap
{
public:
  HashMap();
  virtual ~HashMap();
  void add(T value);
  T get(T *value);
private:
  int hash(T *data);
  T _hashes[26]; //I want a fixed size here
};

template<class T>
HashMap<T>::HashMap()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    this->_hashes[i] = T();
}

template<class T>
HashMap<T>::~HashMap()
{
  //Don't really have anything to delete here?
}

template<class T>
int HashMap<T>::hash(T *dat)
{
  //Super simple, just to try things out
  return (long int) dat % 26;
}

template<class T>
T HashMap<T>::get(T *val)
{
  int idx = this->hash(val);
  cout << idx << endl;
  //Probably somewhere here i get my problem
  if(this->_hashes[idx])
    return this->_hashes[idx];
  return T();
}

template<class T>
void HashMap<T>::add(T val)
{
  //Should probably do some check if there's already an element here.
  this->_hashes[this->hash(&val)] = val;
}
```

The problem im having is that this compiles fine but when I do something like this in my main.cpp:

```
HashMap<char> a = HashMap<char>();
a.add('h');
a.add('c');
a.add('g');
char *b = new char {'c'};
cout << a.get(b) << endl;
delete b;
```

It usually returns the id, ie:

```
4
```

and an empty line which is just a empty char. (the output of the function is in the get() method), but sometimes it will show me something like this:

```
18
g
```

instead of 18 and an empty line. My question is why this happens and how i can prevent it? Does it have something to do with memory not being 'nulled' when it's deleted but just free for other programs to take and then i don't initialise it correctly?
Also, if you have the time please point out any mistakes or not so good to do things in the code.

If it's of any interest im using GCC Debian 4.4.5-8 to compile and compile it with g++ -g file.cpp -o file

Thankful for any help!

Comment: It's probably preferable to use `std::array< T , 26> _hashes` instead of `T _hashes[26]` . Also in the destructor you should delete `_hashes`

Comment: Why are you returning T() in get method. Sorry if I didn't understood something very evident here.

Comment: @shuttle87 I've never even heard of this std class, do you have a link to some documentation? Thanks for the tip! Found some now, reading into it!

Comment: @Shadow Just to return something that an uninitialised value, should perhaps just give a pointer to null or something. Haven't really thought of that part.

Comment: The array is in the header `<array>` , it should be part of any setup with a recent standard library.

Comment: What you are doing _not_ a hash table. It is something like... mm... set. Hash table assumes that you have pair of `key` and `value`. And you get `value` by `key`. Hash table looks like an array where index is not integer, but your own key type.

Comment: Ah, then i've kind of misunderstood the concept of a hashtable, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more idiomatic c++ implementation:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#define MAGIC_NUMBER 26 //rename this to something else preferably

template<class T>
class HashMap
{
    public:
        HashMap();
        virtual ~HashMap(){};
        void add(T value);
        T get(T *value);//potentially confusing that add and get take different types
    private:
        int hash(T *data);
        std::array<T, MAGIC_NUMBER>  _hashes; //I want a fixed size here
};

template<class T>
HashMap<T>::HashMap()
{
    std::fill(_hashes.begin(),_hashes.end(), T());
}

template<class T>
int HashMap<T>::hash(T *dat)
{
    //Super simple, just to try things out
    return (static_cast<int>(*dat)) % MAGIC_NUMBER;//prefer using c++ casts
}

template<class T>
T HashMap<T>::get(T *val) //this is strange, you pass in a pointer and get a non-pointer
{
  int idx = this->hash(val);
  std::cout << idx << std::endl;
  if(this->_hashes[idx])
    return this->_hashes[idx];
  return T();
}

template<class T>
void HashMap<T>::add(T val)
{
  //Should probably do some check if there's already an element here.
  this->_hashes[this->hash(&val)] = val;
}

int main(void){
    HashMap<char> a = HashMap<char>();
    a.add('h');
    a.add('c');
    a.add('g');
    char *b = new char {'c'};
    std::cout << a.get(b) << std::endl;
    delete b;
}
```

Note you will need to compile with c++0x or c++11 features to get the usage of the std::array class. One of the main benefits of the array class is that you get more safety with the memory allocation than just a plain c-style array.

Right now you might want to reconsider some elements of the design. In particular it is confusing that `add` and `get`, have different types. Also this isn't what people generally think about when they hear hashmap, this structure is more like a set.

Also as a coding standards note, if you are prefixing your member variables it's a bit tautological to also use `this->` to access them.

Comment: I'll rename it to a set instead then! Should i return a pointer in the get method to make it more clear? Also, i shouldn't take a pointer in the add cause then the element can be deleted by someone else later?

Comment: With regards to the get method, just make sure you comment/document it well, because it's not intuitive that it works the way it does without looking at the implementation.
If you are worried about memory management then you'd do well to hide the actual pointers in the implementation. Generally speaking if you are coding idiomatic c++ it's good to use RAII and other memory management as much as possible. If you are really worried about contents of the container being deleted you might want to look into shared_ptr.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you see is normal: if you `get` a value that you put in your hash, it will be displayed by your `main`. What is giving you surprising results is your hash function:

```
return (long int) dat % 26;
```

This hashes the `dat` *pointer*, not the `T` that `dat` points to. Try with:

```
return *dat % 26;
```

(Or just use a standard `std::set`.)

Another problem with your code:

```
T _hashes[26]; //I want a fixed size here   (a
```

and

```
this->_hashes = new T[26];                   (b
```

are incompatible. Either use the fixed array (a) and you don't need to allocate it (b), or use a plain pointer (`T *_hashes`) and do (b) - I'm surprised your compiler accepts what you have. If you use (a) you don't need anything in the destructor. If you use (b), you need to `delete []` in your destructor.

Passing a `T*` in get but a `T` in set is a bit strange too.

Comment: The second bit i forgot to edit out, my bad. Fixed now, thanks! Just a follow up question, since it hashes the dat pointer i need the long int if i'm on a 64bit machine, otherwise a normal int would have sufficed? Also, how would i use a `std::set` in the hash function?

Comment: You must **not** hash the pointer, you must hash the `T` (otherwise your structure will be completely useless). Since you only use a modulo, you're restricted to `T`s for which the modulo is defined - the (int) cast I put is probably unnecessary now that I think about it. You wouldn't use a `std::set` in your hash function, you would use that to replace your `HashTable` which isn't a hash table.

Comment: I understood that, but is the long int because i'm on a 64-bit machine? Oh, okay. I'll read up on it then, thanks!

Comment: Whether a pointer has the same bit-length as an `int` or a `long int` on your platform is irrelevant here. If you need an integral type of the same width as a (data) pointer, use `uintprt_t` (but you shouldn't need that very often, if at all).

Comment: I know it's irrelevant but i would like to know if that's the reason i had to use long int to not loose precision when doing the cast?

Comment: Find what the size of `*dat` was and find the size of `int` on your system. If the size of `*dat` was bigger than the size of `int`  you have your answer...

Comment: @Anton: No, you were doing a cast on the pointer itself (the address) when you  should have been dereferencing that pointer. What your hash must hash is the value you're trying to store ('c' for instance), not the bit pattern of the address of where that char is stored in memory.

Comment: I think im to unclear about what im trying to ask now so i'll just try what shuttle87 said x) Thanks for all the help!